# Getting "Class HTML not found" error in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

Working on a new project in Laravel 4 (a.k.a Illuminate) I'm trying to create the link to the style sheet in my `master.blade.php` template like so:

```
    {{ HTML::style('css\style.css') }}
```

But this throws an error saying the class HTML wasn't found. Has it been removed or renamed in Laravel 4, or am I forgetting anything else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The generator type classes such as HTML:: and Form:: have been removed from L4 for best practice reasons. It would be better to render as  tag using the path() method to link the attribute :

```
<link href="{{ path('to/my/style.css') }}" />
```

They may be added in later for backwards compatibility, we will see. Please remember that L4 is currently in an alpha state.

Thanks!
Dayle Rees.

Comment: @daylerees So you recommend use pure HTML ?

Comment: Yeah I don't think the framework should interfere with your front end templates.

Comment: Path is now undefined.  Should we update this answer to use the latest best practice for Googlers?

Comment: It has been added back already, with Html::style() and script(), as iicmaster stated below.

Comment: path() is by the way outdated and replaced with url().

Answer (score 11):

They just bring it back in Apr 02, 2013, But use `Html` instead `HTML`

eg. `{{ Html::style('css\style.css') }}` (now they change it again, this is not working anymore)

Refer: [Add missing HTML::script and HTML::style](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/acc07bdfb35fa0be942c79615719a313de4c51cc)

## Update : Its "HTML" again!!! (Thanks @milad-rey)

for now please use this `{{ HTML::style('css\style.css') }}`

Refer: [Updates for the rename of the `HTML` facade.](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/a982efb49bbf2d107e4a9d7ebc11448d557ee744)

Comment: Thanks for keeping this comment up to date for future Googlers!

Answer (score 4):

HTML and Form classes have been removed. You can install HTML port  with composer here : https://github.com/meido/html

or you can use this (**on Laravel 4 Beta 5**) :

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::to('to/my/style.css') }}" />`

Answer (score 4):

use URL::asset('pathToAsset') ... i'm not quite sure, if this will be deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 4 both the HTML and Form classes have been removed due to existing third party packages that can now be found via composer. You can search for one you like, or meido has ported the existing [HTML](https://github.com/meido/html) and [Form](https://github.com/meido/form) classes over. See their pages for install instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It has been removed.  However there are a couple of things you can do
Try out the: http://laravelbook.github.io/laravel4-powerpack/
The powerpack states that it will bring it back.

OR use the HTML such as mentioned in another post:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::to('pathto/styleheet.css') }}" />
```

For hyperlinks to named routes just in case other people are looking for them as well:

```
echo "<a href=\"" . URL::route('routeNameHere') . "\">Control Page</a>";
or $url = URL::route('routeNameHere');
```

see http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php /* outputs string: http://yoursite.com/pathToAsset */ ?>
{{ URL::asset('/css/style.css') }}
```

---

```
<?php /* outputs html tag: `<a href="http://yoursite.com/home">Home</a>` */ ?>
{{ Html::link('home', 'Home') }}
```

Check `/vendor/laravel/frameworj/src/Illuminate//Html/HtmlBuilder.php` methods. Don't know where the *ell is `/vendor` folder? You've been missing [Composer](http://four.laravel.com/#install-composer).

### composer.json

The best part (no more 'illumination/foundation', 'til now):

```
{
  ...
  "require": {
    ...
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*"
  },
  ...
}
```

### Proved 'til 2013-05-03 12:50