# Load css/js files in Laravel 4 with Composer?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-4

I'm working on creating a new project in Laravel 4. I have a tiny bit of experience in Laravel 3, in which I got used to the assets system. I'm now having a lot of trouble figuring out how to load CSS and JS files in the new system.

I believe I should be using Composer PHP, but I'm not sure how. Where do I put the actual .css and .js files? And then how do I load them with Composer to be utilized in the Laravel project?

I know there are outside plugins like Best Asset, etc. that are written to replicate the Assets system of Laravel 3, but I was hoping to understand the new system and not have to use an outside plugin.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need Composer for your css/js assets. You can use assets pretty much the same as with Laravel 3

You can just place them in your public folder and reference them in your views. You can use plain html, or use the HtmlBuilder: `HTML::style('style.css')` and `HTML::script('script.js')`

Comment: HTMLbuilder is no longer in Laravel 4. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192750/getting-class-html-not-found-error-in-laravel-4

Comment: It has been added back a couple of days ago. See the latest answer in the question you just referenced: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15836987/444215

Comment: Ah you're right, I missed that... Just had to update my vendor/laravel/framework directory. Thanks!

Comment: Its case-sensitive HTML should be in all caps.

Answer (score 1):

You must take care of  case sensitive. 
This class must write with uppercase.

```
HTML::style('style.css');
HTML::script('script.js');
```

[Laravel stylesheets and javascript don't load for non-base routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232600/laravel-stylesheets-and-javascript-dont-load-for-non-base-routes)