# Laravel 4 Javascript Link using {{Html}}

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there any Laravel4 Html() function or way to add a disabled link. Of course I could create the `<a>` tag directly, though I'd prefer to be consistent.

ie:

```
{{ Html::link('javascript:;','Delete',array('id'=>"deletebt")) }}
```

Comment: I just mean something along the lines of <a href="#"> , or <a href="javascript:;>. For now I can do this directly, though new to Laravel and was wondering if there was a better way

Comment: Is that sort of `Html::link()` line working for your install of Laravel 4?  It sounds like one of the changes from Laravel 3 to Laravel 4 was the deprecation of [the HTML class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14192813/1167750) (and [possibly the Form class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14192813/1167750)... although it looks like the Form class is [still in the Laravel 4 docs](http://four.laravel.com/docs/html), at least.)

Comment: It came back recently and was renamed Html instead of HTML. Seems to be working for everything else so far (Not in the docs yet though)

Comment: I believe that the link helper passes URLs through `URL::to()` so that relative links can be made absolute.  In all honesty, links whose purpose is powered by javascript should be generated by javascript.  Is there no "real" path you could use, and remove with javascript instead?

Comment: Nice, nice.  Does that `array()` near the end of your example allow you to use something like `'css' => 'class_names_here'` as an option?  If so, you could always put a label on your link (for example: `'css' => 'enabled'`) and then when you want to disable the link... just search for the `enabled` class in your JavaScript... and switch it with a class named `disabled` (or something similar...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use **link_to**, for example :

```
link_to('link', 'title', array('id' => 'MyId'));
```